# Hard Drive Mounting Error

Tags: hard-drive

I am running **Ubuntu 18.04**, there are (were, at least) **two hard drives: a 650 GB one**, where the OS is installed (one of the partitions) **and another 2TB hard drive** that holds (held) several partitions - all of them for backing up different kinds of data - work, photos, music, so on.

One day, booting the PC took far longer than usual... Once it booted, I couldn't mount any of the partitions **from the 2TB drive**... Here is the message I got:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb3 at /media/aleksandar/a69489c8-7af7-41b1-bfa7-f83925a78354: Command-line `mount -t "ext4" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/sdb3" "/media/aleksandar/a69489c8-7af7-41b1-bfa7-f83925a78354"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb3,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

Here is the output from `dmesg | tail`:

```
:~$ dmesg | tail
[ 1364.134550] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: ATA command pass through(16) 85 06 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e5 00
[ 1964.230102] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 1964.230112] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: ATA command pass through(16) 85 06 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e5 00
[ 2011.616997] perf interrupt took too long (2504 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
[ 2564.188343] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 2564.188353] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: ATA command pass through(16) 85 06 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e5 00
[ 2864.787620] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 2864.787625] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 6e ce 7b 49 00 00 02 00
[ 2864.787627] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1859025737
[ 2864.787641] EXT4-fs (sdb3): unable to read superblock
```

#### Is there anything I could do to get the data back?

===EDIT (thanks **@guiverc**): providing output of `smartctl`:

```
:~$ sudo smartctl -i /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-174-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               /2:0:0:0
Product:              
Compliance:           SPC-5
User Capacity:        600,332,565,813,390,450 bytes [600 PB]
Logical block size:   774843950 bytes
>> Terminate command early due to bad response to IEC mode page
A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.
```

I've tried different commands, such as enabling smart commands section, but with same result:

```
:~$ sudo smartctl -s on /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-174-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF ENABLE/DISABLE COMMANDS SECTION ===
scsiModePageOffset: response length too short, resp_len=47 offset=50 bd_len=46
unable to fetch IEC (SMART) mode page [scsi response fails sanity test]
A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.
```

Comment: I would stop trying to mount/use it, and check the health of the drive using it's inbuilt SMART diagnostic/tools.  You'll then have more of an idea, and can plan the best technique to get the maximum data you can off the drive... ie https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools  (SMART reads data from the chips on the drive and won't cause any further damage)

Comment: @guiverc hi, thanks - I've updated the question to provide the outputs of that tool. Hopefully, that helps to get the better view of the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Those two lines aren't realistic!

```
User Capacity:        600,332,565,813,390,450 bytes [600 PB]
Logical block size:   774843950 bytes
```

I guess your Hard-Drive may be corrupted or a component of your computer failed because 600PB of memory for a 2TB HDD can't be true.
You should more look for hard-drive recovering like if your HDD is corrupted.

Comment: This might be a bit blunt from me, as I am facing this situation for the first time, so please bear with me. Are you saying that this drive is definitely broken and there is nothing I can do (being a common end-user)? The only way to eventually get something out of this would be to give to a hardware professional to try and fix it up?

Comment: I want to say that those two lines are showing unexpected numbers for a 2TB and there is high chance that it's corrupted but it may be an error of the PC itself which failed to read the hard-drive, you could try on another computer if you can.

Comment: Tried, I got exactly the same behavior.

Comment: I think the best would be to ask to someone else or a specialist, because 600PB HDDs in a 2TB one don't exit as far I know.